# Draw Line chart in jQuery using data from an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, linechart

I am trying to generate line chart in jQuery. Here is my AJAX request code:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
$.ajax({
    url: '/turnover/DrawLineChart'+ queryString, 
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        ?????????
    },
}
});
```

Here is the data in the response:

[image]

How can I draw a line chart using this data? Here my X-axis data is static (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec). In the response I have the Y-axis data. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com

Comment: thank you.. i have got the output..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what about the license of this(highchart) js files ????

Comment: It's free unless you're using it for commercial purposes.